# How to add remove button for each tab added

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Hi I need add a remove button for each tab added:

```
var count = 1;
    $('#addspan').click(function() {
                $('#wrap').show();
                count = $('#wrap').tabs("length") + 1;
                $('#wrap').append('contents');
                $('#wrap').tabs("add", "#page" + count, count);

            });
```

The above code add tab dynamically, but i would like to add a **remove button** for each tab added dynamically.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What jQuery version do you have?

Comment: jquery-1.7.2.js jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty tricky but I was able to set up a fiddle to make it work (http://jsfiddle.net/qJNZr/19/).  The relevant javascript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    var count = $('#tabs').tabs('length') + 1;
    $('#add').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('add', '#page' + count, count);
        $('#page' + count).append($('<a>remove</a>').addClass('remove').attr('href', '#'));
        count = count+1;
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'a.remove', function(e, ui){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('remove', '#' + $(this).parents('div').attr('id'));
    });
});
​
```

So basically I'm adding a remove link on the newly added tabs.  A live event handler looks for that link and removes the tab it's on.